# Face Detection in iOS 8 using OpenCV gets slow after several seconds

Tags: opencv, ios8, face-detection

I am developing and iOS app that uses OpenCV to detect Faces on realtime from the camera.

On iOS 7 devices it works without any kind of problem. However on iOS 8 devices it starts detecting (or trying to detect) the faces and after 4-5 seconds the FPS decrements from 30FPS to 20FPS (in the case of iPhone 6, other devices change the FPS).

I am using:

- OpenCV 2.4.9
- `CvVideoCamera` to get every frame from the camera.
- `Cascade Classifier` for face detection.

My `VieController.mm` has the following code to setup the camera and process the image for face detection.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //Init camera and configuration

    self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:self.imageVideoView];
    self.videoCamera.delegate = self;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30;
    self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = NO;

    //Load Cascade Model for Face Detection

    NSString* cascadeModel = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2" ofType:@"xml"];
    const char* cascadeModel_path = [cascadeModel fileSystemRepresentation];

    if(face_cascade.load(cascadeModel_path)){
        cascadeLoad = true;
    }else{
        cascadeLoad = false;
    }

    //Start camera
    [self.videoCamera start];

    // Init frames to 0 and start timer to refresh the frames each second
    totalFrames = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(computeFPS) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void) processImage:(Mat&)image {

    try{
        if(cascadeLoad && !image.empty()){
            // Opencv Face Detection
            cv::Mat frameH;
            pyrDown(image, frameH);
            face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frameH, faces, 1.2, 2, 0, cv::Size(50, 50));

            //Draw an ellipse on each detected Face
            for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
            {
                cv::Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
                ellipse( image, center, cv::Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

            }

        }
    } catch (cv::Exception e) {
        NSLog(@"CV EXCEPTION!");
    }

    //Add one frame
    totalFrames++;

}

//Function called every second to update the frames and update the FPS label
- (void)        computeFPS {
    [self.lblFPS setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d fps", totalFrames]];
    totalFrames = 0;
}
```

That's all my code.

With the following test project the image does not look on Portrait (I have not figure out yet why). But the problem with decreasing the FPS is happening.
If you want to test it, the link to my complete test project is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_JyM5lV3MifTkkybHA1QThSblk/view?usp=sharing).

Has anyone faced this problem? Any idea what might be happening or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

PS: I have also read that there is other Face Detectors for iOS like the `CIDetector`, but I am using OpenCV as I want to do some more processing in OpenCV with the faces.

Comment: detectors search throughout the image (sliding window) in multiple scales. you may try to preprocess the image - skin color thresholding - crop out insignificant parts and enhance the algorithm..

Comment: Hi canberk, thanks for the suggestion. I am already reducing the image before running the Face Detector, thanks to that the detector can run to 30FPS. My problem is, that on iOS8 devices only (not iOS 7), after several seconds detecting the face at 30FPS the speed gets cut down to 20FPS and keeps steady. It looks more like iOS8 cut my program somehow, that iOS7 does not.